# How to intercept play/pause button presses on samsung headsets?

Tags: android

I am talking about those white earphones that come with every Samsung smartphone. They come with 3 remote buttons. Volume up, down and play/pause. So how can I intercept or react on pressed events? Especially the play/pause button makes me headaches as I haven't found any working solution on that.
Please help!

Comment: I think you are looking for this . http://android.amberfog.com/?p=415

Comment: I get an error for the parameter used in setPriority()..